# Pickle fit-object

Tags: object, save, pickle, lmfit

I wrote a class where some data are fitted. Since the *fitting* takes very long when lots of data have to be fitted, I want to save the fit-object of this class so I do not have to **repeat** the fitting when I want to use the fitted data later. Using pickle, I get the following error calling the save method on an object:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'ConstantModel.__init__.<locals>.constant'
```

I only have this problem when pickle the fitted data, pickle works if I save the object before fitting.
Is there a way to pickle fitted data or is there a nice workaround?

```
class pattern:
    def fitting(self):
        mod_total = lmfit.models.ConstantModel()
        pars_total = mod_total.guess(self.y, x=self.x)

        self.fit = mod_total.fit(self.y, pars_total, x=self.x)

    def save(self, path):
        with open(path, 'wb') as filehandler: 
            pickle.dump(self, filehandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem: Using `dill` instead of `pickle` works *(as I want it to do).*